# How do I add a table to the third tab of my shiny app below?

Tags: r, shiny, choropleth

[image]I've attached a photo of what I want to create.

This is what my code looks like for that portion:

UI:

```r
 tabPanel(

      "Explore the Risk Index Data",
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                    choices = c(
                      "19102", "19103", "19104", "19106", "19107", "19112", "19121", "19122",
                      "19123", "19125", "19130", "19132", "19133", "19134", "19137", "19140",
                      "19141", "19143", "19145", "19146", "19147", "19148", "19149", "19151",
                      "19152", "19153", "19154"
                    )),
        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
      )
```

Use input from ui to create data table,

```r
  output$place_data = DT::renderDataTable({
    place_data[, c("zip", "Risk", "Poverty", "Education", "Unemployment", "Crime", "ACEs", "Utilization", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet(map)
```

I tried editing the code with different types of inputs like zipcodes and the names of the categories but it doesn't appear. I am not sure how I can approach this.

Here is the code for the example in the picture:
#-----------------------------------
# Intro Reactives
#-----------------------------------
#-----------------------------------
# Library
#-----------------------------------

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


server <- function(input, output) {
  # Use input from ui to create data table,
  # put on shuttle to ui
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]

  })
}


#-----------------------------------
# UI
#-----------------------------------

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # create a drop-down
```

selectInput(
"variable",
"Variable:",
c(
"Cylinders" = "cyl",
"Transmission" = "am",
"Gears" = "gear"
)
),

```
  # pop-out the table
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
))

#-----------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#-----------------------------------
```

Comment: The id in the UI needs to match the id in the server e.g. for a DT output you could pair up `DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")` with `output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(...)`. Shiny doesn't know which element to put where if the names don't match.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you include a fully reproducible example - include some data, so we can see what the problem is a little bit easier.

Comment: @nrennie Thanks! I changed both to mytable but I am getting this error: 
"undefined columns selected" in the third tab. Do you know what could be wrong? I'll edit the post with my full code.

Comment: Your input variable is selecting one of the values in "19102", "19103", "19104", ... , and you're trying to select a column with this name. Does your data set place_data have a column with that name?

The mtcars